# Manipulate CSV-date variables in Jmeter Automation

Tags: api, post, jmeter

I'm using the Jmeter to validate the dates for a POST API service.but,need to pass the dates as dynamic from CSV file.
provided parameters as ID,stop Date and Start Date. Condition: stop date should be 2 days from current date and start Date should be <30 days >180 days. How can I use a CSV data values ?

used some BeanShell date manipulators. but, unable to find a way to use with csv data to automate.

Answer (score 0):

Use "jp@gc - Variables From CSV File" plugin to fetch data from the csv. Please check the output below:-

[image]

This is just an example. Modified it according to your requirement.

Hope this helps.